How to submit transaction faster to the Arbitrum sequencer?
I have been trying for a few weeks, DEX arbitrage on Arbitrum One.
I wanted to know where the sequencer could be located (according to dig/nslookup) it seems to be in US west, but I am not 100% sure. Also I am seeing some addresses being able to inlcude tx in block n+1 (with liquidity movements in block n). While even when I colocate close to the sequencer, I can at best only be included in block n+2.
Do you think some addresses have favored treatment on the sequencer ? Arbitrum say they do not reorder transaction, but the more I work on this project, the less I trust this.
Any tips ?
